# Rollup + PostCSS + Source Maps

Tags: build, rollup, postcss

It appears that using Rollup and PostCSS together, you end up with a function named `__$injectStyle`, which "injects" to CSS into the page by creating a `<style>` element and adding it to the header.

This works fine, but it doesn't include a source map for those blocks. This means I can't get the benefits of a source map when working with my CSS. This is a big problem. When I have a CSS source map, I can actually edit the source files and see the CSS changes in real time, which is a major help.

I'm using the method where I `import` the source map into my JavaScript files (in conjunction with Babel and CommonJS).

Is there a way to get Rollup and PostCSS to play nice with source maps?